# Python Printing Row and Column number on 2d matrix?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print output as follows.

Strings: ["cat", "dog", "big"]

```
Print:
      0  1  2
0     c  a  t 
1     d  o  g
2     b  i  g
```

But I can't seem to print the indices properly

```
for i in a:
  for j in i:
    print(j, end=' ')
  print()
```

I know this prints the matrix itself but doesn't give me the row and column numbers I need

Comment: That isn’t a 2D array though, right? Is this purely for display as a string?

Comment: Also, are we to assume that the strings will always be the same length?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal job for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ["cat", "dog", "big"]

df = pd.DataFrame([[y for y in x] for x in lst])
print(df)

#    0  1  2
# 0  c  a  t 
# 1  d  o  g
# 2  b  i  g
```

Comment: why you include DataFrame ??

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper, This is more than mere printing.

Answer (score 1):

please try below:

```
str_list = ["cat", "dog",  "big"]
print (" ", " ".join([str(x) for x in range(len(str_list))]))
for i, x in enumerate(str_list):
  print (i, " ".join(x))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your output without using any library by following code, Otherwise PANDAS would be helpful for oneliner

```
str = ['cat','dog','big']

r = 0
c = 0
print('  ',end='')
for i in range(0,(max([len(i) for i in str]))):
    print(c,end=' ')
    c+=1
print()
for i in str:
    print(r,end=' ')
    for j in i:
        print(j , end=' ')
    print()
    r+=1
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ta-da! This solution should work regardless of list dimensions.

```py
str_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'loooong', 'big']

max_row_len = len(max(str_list, key=len))

#header
print('  ', end='')
print(*range(max_row_len), sep=' ')

#rows
for idx, val in enumerate(str_list):
    print(idx, end=' ')
    print(*val, sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 c a t
1 d o g
2 l o o o o n g
3 b i g
```